# entr not working on some specific file

Tags: arch-linux, dwm

I was trying to customise my dwm status bar to react automatically on battery status change using `entr` but it doesn't seem to work. For testing that, I tried
`printf "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status" | entr -s 'printf "Hello\n"'`,
but nothing happens when I disconnect my laptop's power supply. I can see using `cat` that the file changes from Charging to Discharging, but `entr` doesn't print `Hello`.